# Need to update a value in a cell based on another cell value from the list in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, updates

I have Excel macro-enabled sheet - Chart.xlsm-  where the values are selected from the lists:

[image]

My goal is - when selecting Column D (Type of Workday) = "Day Off" then I want the columns E (Day Outcome) and F (Reason) will be automatically updated with "Not Applicable" value.

My values for (Type of Workday), (Day Outcome) and (Reason) columns selections are stored in this same macro spreadsheet file, but in a separate sheets if that's important

I am not a vba savvy so I tried to use the following code (with no success):

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Dim sh As Worksheet
       Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh.Cells(3,4) = “Day Off” Then
       Sh.Cells(3,5) = “Not Applicable”
    End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you put the code?

Comment: @norie  I put it under right click, View Code, Worksheet, Change

It gives error "Expected Then or Go To"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the code to run when a value is selected in column D you can try this.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        If Target.Value = "Day Off" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(,1).Resize(,2).Value = "Not Applicable"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If
```